# Ошибка "Параметр задан неверно" при закрытии формы

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

Проблема в следующем: при закрытии формы срабатывает эта ошибка.
Суть в том, что я делаю форму прозрачной в тот момент, когда она не активна. Когда форма активируется, то снимаю прозрачность.

Код формы:

```
private void Main_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Opacity = 0.9;
}
private void Main_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Opacity = 1;
}
```

**Почему форма закрывается с ошибкой и как решить эту проблему?**

**UPD**: *Понял, на каком месте стопорится программа.
После того, как форма закрылась - происходит активация события "Main_Deactivate". Там срабатывает параметр прозрачности формы и вот тут появляется ошибка.*

[image: Ошибка параметра]

Comment: а отладка на каком моменте стопается и что выдает?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, в общем, обнаружил то, что - после того, как форма закрылась - происходит активация события Main_Deactivate. Там срабатывает параметр прозрачности формы и вот тут появляется ошибка.
P.S.: в описание темы вопроса включил.

Comment: Main_Deactivate на каком евенте? при потере фокуса?

Comment: так наверное не надо менять параметры уже закрытой формы - в жтом может быть и есть просблема?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, да. Форма становится немного прозрачной при потери фокуса и принимает нормальную прозрачность при активации формы снова.

Comment: @tym32167, в этом и проблема. Я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы после закрытия формы это событие не срабатывало, а во всех остальных срабатывало...

Comment: отпишитись от события при зыкрытии формы

Comment: ну подпишитесь на `FormClosing`, в обработчике отпишитесь от остальных событий

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, каким образом?

Comment: @tym32167, если я отпишусь от остальных, перестанет работать фишка с прозрачностью...

Comment: вам правильно ответили...не перестанет, т к отписка будет происходи после того как вы нажмете на закрытие формы

Comment: а зачем она вам для закрытой формы?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц понял, попробую разобраться. Просто я не знаю как отписываться от событий в самом событии )).

Comment: `form1.LostFocus -= (s, e)`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, не помогло. Попытался отписаться от события `Main_Deactivate` в событии `FormClosing` с помощью вашей строчки. Или я просто не допер, как это сделать.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, спасибо огромное! **Помогло!** Разобрался. Щас ответ тогда напишу сюда.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, разобрался наконец с этим. **Спасибо за помощь!**

Про события и про то, что от них отписываться можно и во время выполнения самого события я впервые узнал. 
Буду теперь в курсе.

Материал брал отсюда: [Подписка и отмена подписки на события (MSDN)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)

В итоге, надо было просто отписаться от события `Main_Deactivate(*)` во время выполнения события `Main_FormClosing(*)`. И что мы имеем: во время закрытия формы мы просто отписываемся от выполнения события потери фокуса формы и закрываем форму.

Итоговый код моей формы:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Server
{
    public partial class Server : Form
    {
        public Server()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Server_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e) // смена прозрачности, когда форма не активна
        {
            Opacity = 0.9; // тут раньше была ошибка
        }
        private void Server_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e) // убираем прозрачность, когда форма снова активна
        {
            Opacity = 1;
        }
        private void Server_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Deactivate -= new EventHandler(this.Server_Deactivate); // вот тут отписываемся от события потери фокуса
        }
    }
}
```